# MySQL Stored Procedure erro

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am getting this error

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lstart, lend; END IF; ELSE IF lstart = -1 THEN select count(*) a' at line 8"`

on this stored procedure creation on server but in my localhost phpmyadmin it is creating without any error?

```
DELIMITER
create procedure getallmedia(IN cat int(2), IN asc_desc varchar(5), IN lstart int(11), IN lend int(11))
BEGIN
IF cat = -1 THEN
    IF asc_desc = 'asc' THEN
        IF lstart = -1 THEN
            select count(*) as result from bc_media where id <> -1;
        ELSE
            select * from bc_media where id <> -1 limit lstart, lend;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF lstart = -1 THEN
            select count(*) as result from bc_media where category = cat;
        ELSE
            select * from bc_media where category = cat order by id desc limit lstart, lend;
        END IF;
    END IF;
ELSE
    IF asc_desc = 'asc' THEN
        IF lstart = -1 THEN
            select count(*) as result from bc_media where category = cat;
        ELSE
            select * from bc_media where category = cat limit lstart, lend;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF lstart = -1 THEN
            select count(*) as result from bc_media where category = cat;
        ELSE
            select * from bc_media where category = cat order by id desc limit lstart, lend;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Help me out please :(

Comment: Some mysql versions(older one) don't support dynamic limits....maybe your dev and production mysql versions are not the same...

Comment: Check [SQL Fiddle demo MySQL 5.5.32](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f51a9f/1). Then try the same code using 5.1.61 version of MySQL to reproduce the problem. From documentation: "Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.". See [13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but, at the **first DELIMITER** try to put $$

And after the last **END** put $$